# errors inserting variables in mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, modx-evolution

I am trying to insert four variables into a mysql table. The following mysql INSERT statement produces T_STRING errors. I would be grateful if any one can advise where my error is in the syntax.

```
function add_student($name, $phone, $email, $id) {
global $modx;
$session_id = intval($id, 10);
$query = $modx->db->INSERT INTO `xtra_students`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `session_id`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$session_id');    
return $query;
}
```

The first 3 variables are varchar and the $session_id is an int(4).

Comment: Please first read documentation for [*`Modx API:DB:query`*](http://rtfm.modx.com/evolution/1.0/developers-guide/api-reference/dbapi/query)

Comment: I am not familiar with your class, but at first glance `$modx->db->INSERT INTO` won't work, because the syntax is wrong. There must be no spaces in method names or you will have to wrap it in curlies, like so `$modx->db->{'INSERT INTO'}`.

Comment: Re: Putting this question on hold. I disagree with the premise that there is no opportunity for users to learn from this example. The correction of code by more knowledgeable programmers provides good lessons for both me (OP) and other users who have similar problems. I for one have learn't a great deal just from this single exercise. Thank you to those who have contributed to this in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a function call and the quotes around the string:

```
$query = $modx->db->query("INSERT INTO `xtra_students`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `session_id`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$session_id')");
```

Comment: Thank you for your replies. yes, this worked as far as not producing the errors and successfully navigating to the Thank you page. But sadly the database table did not create a new row with the inserted data. So I accept your answer and guess I'll need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = $modx->db->INSERT INTO `xtra_students`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `session_id`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$session_id');
```

This line is the problem, you need to wrap mysql query by quotes, I don't know what's your `$modx->db->` but it may look like this:

```
$modx->db->query("INSERT INTO `xtra_students`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `session_id`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$session_id')");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$modx->db->query("INSERT INTO `xtra_students`(`name`, `phone`, `email`, `session_id`) VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', '$session_id')");
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer.*

Comment: The statement required parenthesis and quotation marks around it. These were missing from my  original code  ("INSERT INTO.......")